# Phonegap Build: Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12+

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, phonegap-build, phonegap

I was running into a problem yesterday dealing with gradle. To solve this issue I did the following:

```
$phonegap platform remove android
$phonegap platform add android@^6.3.0 (previously i was using 6.3.0, this moved it to 6.4.0)
$brew update && brew install gradle
```

now when I build the project locally everything is happy and no errors

when I go to phonegap build and build it remotely i get a failure:

```
* What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'www_android'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.

  > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12+.

  Versions that do not match:

  11.0.4

  11.0.2

  11.0.1

  11.0.0

  10.2.6

  + 18 more

  Searched in the following locations:

  file:/opt/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm /maven-metadata.xml

  file:/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml

  file:/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/

  file:/opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gc m/maven-metadata.xml

  file:/opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gc m/

  file:/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml

  file:/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/

  Required by:

  project :



* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

  at ChildProcess.whenDone (/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)

  at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)

  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)

  at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)

  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
```

some more context:

- using cli-7.0.1
- engine name="android" spec="6.4.0" (AS MENTIONED ABOVE THIS WAS: 6.3.0)

**project.properties:**

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.gradle.include.1=bidwrangler-opentok-plugin/stevechuppauctions-build-extras.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller/stevechuppauctions-SafariView Controller-java18.gradle
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:customtabs:23.2.0
cordova.gradle.include.3=phonegap-plugin-push/stevechuppauctions-push.gradle
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v13:23+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11+
cordova.system.library.4=me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.14@aar
```

I tried updating packages through Android Studio but this not seem to help at all.

Comment: Which plugins do you have?

Answer (score 0):

```
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.1
```

Have you tried updating your project.properties with this?

I have found two things are usually needed. All of the google and firebase stuff must be set at the same version in the project.properties, and this needs to be added to it as well:

```
cordova.system.library.7=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0
```

Comment: If I update these by hand they will be wiped out though when I go do a fresh build.

Comment: Your project.properties should not get wiped out.  That should be set by you.